# How to emulate wc -l in Raku

Tags: perl, raku

In perl 5, you can emulate `wc -l` using oneliner:

`perl -lnE 'END {say $.}' test.txt`

How to implement this functionality on Raku

If you try to implement this:

`raku -e 'say "test.txt".IO.open.lines.elems'`

it turns out to be slow and uses a lot of memory

Information for reproduce:

```
$ wget http://eforexcel.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1500000%20Sales%20Records.zip
$ unzip "1500000 Sales Records.zip"
$ mv "1500000 Sales Records.csv" part.txt
$ for i in `seq 1 10`; do cat part.txt >> test.txt ; done
$ du -sh test.txt
1.8G    test.txt

$ time wc -l test.txt
15000000 test.txt

real    0m0,350s
user    0m0,143s
sys     0m0,205s

$ time perl -lnE 'END { say $. }' test.txt
15000001

real    0m1,981s
user    0m1,719s
sys     0m0,256s

$ time raku -e 'say "test.txt".IO.open.lines.elems'
15000001

real    2m51,852s
user    0m25,129s
sys     0m6,378s

# Using swap (maximum uses 2.2G swap):
# Before `raku -e ''`

$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15009        1695       12604         107         708       12917
Swap:          7583           0        7583

# After `raku -e ''`

$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15009         752       13923          72         332       13899
Swap:          7583         779        6804

# Swap not used
$ time raku -ne '++$ andthen END .say' test.txt
15000001

real    1m44,906s
user    2m14,165s
sys     0m0,653s

$ raku -v
This is Rakudo version 2019.11 built on MoarVM version 2019.11
implementing Perl 6.d.
```

Comment: Could you add timing information, and the actual output of `wc` (which should include file size).  Thank you.

Comment: Update question - added example for reproduce

Comment: @TheAthlete Thanks for the added info. I think it likely this will be an historically interesting [raku] SO because of rakudo's presumable steady closing of the performance gap over coming years so please consider adding a couple further bits of info. First, although it's clear you're using a recent rakudo (because you're writing `raku`) it would still be good to have `raku -v` output. Also, please consider adding the output of the timing of my current suggestion. Also, I may look into switching to the `'ascii'` decoder later this weekend to produce a better time.

Comment: On a side note: `-l` flag for perl slows down the perl significantly and it's not useful in this case. On my machine for a file with random line length and about 200k lines, removing `-l` results in a 40% improvement.

Answer (score 8):

One option that's still likely to be pretty slow compared to `perl` but worth comparing:

```
raku -ne '++$ andthen END .say' test.txt
```

The `l` command line option is redundant.

[`$`](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#index-entry-$_(variable)) is an anonymous state scalar.

[`andthen`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/andthen) tests that its lhs is defined, and if so, sets that value as the topic (`$_`) and then evaluates its rhs.

[`END`](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/END) is similar to `perl`'s `END`. Note that it returns `Nil` to the `andthen` but that doesn't matter here because we're using the `END`'s statement for its side-effect.

Several things will impact this code's speed. Some things I can think of:

- **Compiler startup overhead.** Ignoring any modules being used, the `raku` compiler Rakudo has a startup overhead of about a tenth of a second on typical hardware compared to a fairly negligible one for `perl`.
- **The notion of a "line".** In `perl`, the default notion of line processing is reading a series of bytes, some of which represent a line end. In `raku`, the default notion of line processing is reading a UTF-8 string, some of which represents line ends. Thus `perl` only incurs the reading overhead of an ASCII (or Extended ASCII) decoder whereas `raku` incurs the reading overhead of a UTF-8 decoder.
- **Compiler optimizations.** `perl` is generally optimized to the max. It wouldn't surprise me if `perl -lnE 'END {say $.}' test.txt` takes advantage of some clever optimizations. In contrast, work on Rakudo optimization is still in its early days relatively speaking.

The only things I think anyone can do about the first and last of the three points I've mentioned above are to wait N years and/or contribute to the compiler's improvement.

There will be a way to work around raku's UTF-8-by-default. Perhaps something like the following is already doable and significantly faster than raku's default, at least ignoring the overhead of using a module called `foo`:

```
raku -Mfoo -ne '++$ andthen END .say' test.txt
```

where module `foo` switches the default encoding for file I/O to ASCII or whatever from [the available encodings](https://docs.raku.org/type/Encoding::Registry).

I haven't checked that this is actually doable in current Rakudo but would be surprised if were not.